# Counting number of times a digit occurs in a column of numbers in Stata

Tags: stata

Here's an example of the data I currently have stored under one variable, `complications` in Stata:

Complications: 1; 1 10; 1 3 10

Frequency: 320; 10; 5

Each number is associated with a specific complication and a person can have one or more complications. I need to generate 10 categorical variables to capture the number of people who don't/ do have each complication. For example, for complication 1, complication_1 = 0 is for those who do not have it, and complication_1 = 1 is for those who do have it. What is the most efficient way for me to do this for each complication in Stata?

Comment: Too much guesswork needed here. Please show a reproducible example with code to input data. How do you know which person is which?

Answer (score 0):

Echoing @Nick's comment: please make a big-enough effort when posting questions. Read carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. Research is also expected, but you show none in your original post.

My guess:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
id  str12 comp
1 "1"
2 "1 10"
3 "1 3 10"
4 "4"
5 "4 22 10"
end

list

*----- what you want ? -----

// split
split comp, gen(comp)
drop comp

// reshape
reshape long comp, i(id)
drop if missing(comp)

// create indicators
tab comp, gen(comp)

list, sepby(id)
```

Why you need these indicator variables is another matter. Newer versions of Stata (starting Stata 11) count with *factor-variable notation*. See `help factor variables`, if pertinent.